# How can I auto-flow: column but specify the columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I would like to have a CSS grid that renders the items column by column, where the max number of columns and rows is not assumed. I have below the best version that I was able to come up with, although with some workarounds that I am hoping to not be required:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.item {
  margin: 1em;
}

.column {
  display: contents;
}

.clear {
  grid-row-end: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">A1</div>
    <div class="item">A2</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">B1</div>
    <div class="item">B2</div>
    <div class="item">B3</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">C1</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see:

- The CSS hard codes the number of rows using `grid-template-rows`. Removing this will cause items to appear in incorrect columns if there are more items than the hard-coded number of rows, while making the hard-coded number extremely large (e.g., 1000) will work for all practical number of items in a column, but cause a large amount of blank space to be added to the bottom of the document.
- There is a "clear" div that I'd rather not need in each column to force the auto-placement to the next column.

Note that just having each column lay itself out (using something like flexbox or CSS Columns) will not work, as it is important that the grid items (which may have varying heights) remain aligned with their horizontal neighbors.

Comment: if you remove display:contents and you remove `grid-template-rows` and your remove the clear element, you have what you want, no?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not quite. What happens in that case is that there are three columns, each with a single row. Since each of the items would all be within the single row, I lose the grid being able to ensure that horizontally neighboring items are properly aligned. e.g., if "B1" was larger than "A1", then "A2" and "B2" would not be horizontally aligned.

Comment: and you want all the rows to be equal OR only an alignment between element inside the same row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get rid of the `clear` element by setting the row of the first element of each column then you can consider the trick of a big number of rows but with `auto` sizing and not `1fr`. You won't have any blank space if you don't use row gaps:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1000, auto);
}

.item {
  margin: 1em;
}

.column {
  display: contents;
}

.column .item:first-child {
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">A1</div>
    <div class="item">A2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">B1</div>
    <div class="item">B2</div>
    <div class="item">B3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">C1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```